# How to make SmartFilters bookmarkable?

Tags: sapui5, bookmarks

I'm looking for a concept of making SmartFilters on SmartFilterBar bookmarkable. It would be great if you share some links or your own knowledge and thoughts on this topic.

I'm searching for something like in these links, but for SmartFilters.

- [Table sorting bookmarkable](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/39759878ae4f48dcad0cf34da1d299f0)
- [Dialog bookmarkable](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/5cc3147afc8d4854b5d3c5fc20923f77)

Comment: You mean saving a particular filter combination right? Variant management does that. See the persistencyKey on the Filter bar control [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/api/sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar%23methods/getPersistencyKey), or search for variant management and LREP. There's some additional info in the [documentation](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/topic/b1d4d261524b4a3da78547ed4283a082)

Comment: @Jorg, I know about variant managment, but i need, for example, to copy link with filters, then send it to another person in order he will follow the link and see filters i have set. I know i can save variant managment and make it public, but it also doesn't match my case. I need to pass filters in the url parameters ( like ?param=value). Thanks